# Error 501 by sending mail using Swift mailer

Tags: php

```
<?php

  require_once '../plugin/swift/lib/swift_required.php';

  // Create the Transport
  $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('pod51003.outlook.com',587,'tls')
    ->setUsername('user@connect.polyu.hk')
    ->setPassword('pw')
    ;

  // Create the Mailer using your created Transport
  $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

  // Create a message
  $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
    ->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))
    ->setTo(array('foodil@hotmail.com', 'foodil@yahoo.com.hk' => 'A name'))
    ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
    ;

  // Send the message
  $result = $mailer->send($message);

  printf("Sent %d messages\n", $result);

?>
```

It turned out:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' 
with message 'Expected response code 250 but got code "501", with message "501 5.5.4 Invalid domain name "' 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\fyp\plugin\swift\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php:422 

Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\fyp\plugin\swift\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(306): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_assertResponseCode('501 5.5.4 Inval...', Array) 
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\fyp\plugin\swift\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\EsmtpTransport.php(224): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->executeCommand('HELO [::1]??', Array, Array) 
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\fyp\plugin\swift\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(323): Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->executeCommand('HELO [::1]??', Array) 
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\fyp\plugin\swift\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\EsmtpTransport.php(272): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_doHeloCommand() 
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\fyp\plugin\swift\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(124) in C:\xampp\htdocs\fyp\plugin\swift\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php on line 422
```

Actually I follow the tutorial straightly, so is that any thing I omitted in my code? The SMTP server information is valid.

> ***External SMTP setting:***
>   Server name: **pod51003.outlook.com** - you can also see the note below on how to determine the server name
>   Port: **587**
>   Encryption method: **TLS**

after adding the line: there is another error:

```
Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto() [streams.crypto]: this stream does not support SSL/crypto in C:\xampp\htdocs\fyp\plugin\swift\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php on line 102

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' 
with message 'Unable to connect with TLS encryption' 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\fyp\plugin\swift\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\EsmtpTransport.php:283 

Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\fyp\plugin\swift\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(124): Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->_doHeloCommand() 
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\fyp\plugin\swift\lib\classes\Swift\Mailer.php(79): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start() 
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\fyp\mail\send.php(26): Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message)) 
#3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\fyp\plugin\swift\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\EsmtpTransport.php on line 283
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding this line here as shown:

```
// Create the Transport
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('pod51003.outlook.com',587,'tls')
->setUsername('user@connect.polyu.hk')
->setPassword('pw')
;

// ADD THIS LINE
$transport->setLocalDomain('[127.0.0.1]');

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
```

I'm guessing your SMTP server doesn't like/understand IPv6, based on the response you are getting to the HELO command.

Comment: Another error after adding the line, pls have a look, thanks a lot

Comment: still have the problem of 550 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender

Comment: I'm guessing that is because the `From:` email address you are using does not match the email address associated with username/password you have used to authenticate against the SMTP server. Try setting a `Reply-To:` address and sending as your own account.