# Send Mails in Java class error 501

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have a problem, I'm trying to sent a sample email using the following servlet:

```
package mail;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author bog
 */
public class mail1 extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, AddressException, MessagingException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("try");
            final String username = "progweb2";

            final String password = "lollosoissimo";
            out.println("set pwd");

 // Get a Properties object to set the mailing configuration 
 // parameters
            Properties props = System.getProperties();

            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.mail.yahoo.com");

            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");

            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

            props.put("mail.debug", "true");

 //We create the session object with the authentication information
            out.println("create session obj");
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
                ;
                @Override

                protected PasswordAuthentication
                        getPasswordAuthentication() {

                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);

                }

            });
            //Create a new message
            session.setDebug (true);
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

 //Set the FROM and TO fields –
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username + "yahoo.com"));

            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("dest@mail.com"));

            msg.setSubject("Hello da gmail");

            msg.setText("come stai ");

            //msg.setSentDate(new Date());

            System.out.println("\nTrying to send email...\n");

 //We create the transport object to actually send the e-mail
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");

            transport.connect("smtp.mail.yahoo.com", 465, username, password);
            out.println("sensing msgto "+msg.getAllRecipients());
            transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
            out.println("before closing tx");
            transport.close();
            out.println("close tx");

            System.out.println("\nEmail sent!\n");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {

            e.printStackTrace(); 

        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(mail1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(mail1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Everything stopes right after printing
`out.println("sensing msgto "+msg.getAllRecipients());` on the web page, just like the following istruction fails.
But I get this error in my Tomcat console:

```
09-Jul-2015 23:13:59.343 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-92] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/CinemaBooking] has started
09-Jul-2015 23:13:59.349 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-92] database.DBManager.shutdown No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:;shutdown=true
09-Jul-2015 23:13:59.351 WARNING [http-nio-8084-exec-92] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [CinemaBooking] registered the JDBC driver [org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
09-Jul-2015 23:13:59.627 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-92] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/CinemaBooking] is completed
09-Jul-2015 23:16:31.480 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-82] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/CinemaBooking] has started
09-Jul-2015 23:16:31.484 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-82] database.DBManager.shutdown No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:;shutdown=true
09-Jul-2015 23:16:31.486 WARNING [http-nio-8084-exec-82] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [CinemaBooking] registered the JDBC driver [org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
09-Jul-2015 23:16:31.998 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-82] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/CinemaBooking] is completed
09-Jul-2015 23:17:02.712 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-97] null.null No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:;shutdown=true
09-Jul-2015 23:17:02.715 WARNING [http-nio-8084-exec-97] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [CinemaBooking] registered the JDBC driver [org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
09-Jul-2015 23:17:03.220 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-97] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/CinemaBooking]
09-Jul-2015 23:17:08.268 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-101] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor /home/bog/.netbeans/8.0.2/apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base/conf/Catalina/localhost/CinemaBooking.xml
09-Jul-2015 23:17:08.270 WARNING [http-nio-8084-exec-101] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule.begin [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'antiJARLocking' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
09-Jul-2015 23:17:08.525 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-101] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor /home/bog/.netbeans/8.0.2/apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base/conf/Catalina/localhost/CinemaBooking.xml has finished in 257 ms
09-Jul-2015 23:17:08.537 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-96] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start The start() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/CinemaBooking]] after start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.5
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.5

Trying to send email...

DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.mail.yahoo.com", port 465, isSSL true
220 smtp.mail.yahoo.com ESMTP ready
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.mail.yahoo.com", port: 465

EHLO bog-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S510p
250-smtp.mail.yahoo.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 41697280
250-8 BITMIME
250 AUTH PLAIN LOGIN XOAUTH2 XYMCOOKIE
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "41697280"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8", arg "BITMIME"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN XOAUTH2 XYMCOOKIE"
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
DEBUG SMTP: check mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM 
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<progweb2yahoo.com>
501 Syntax error in arguments
DEBUG SMTP: got response code 501, with response: 501 Syntax error in arguments

RSET
250 flushed
DEBUG SMTP: MessagingException while sending
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 501 Syntax error in arguments
;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 501 Syntax error in arguments

com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 501 Syntax error in arguments
;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 501 Syntax error in arguments

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2114)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1618)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1119)
    at mail.mail1.processRequest(mail1.java:105)
    at mail.mail1.doGet(mail1.java:144)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2114)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1618)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1119)
    at mail.mail1.processRequest(mail1.java:105)
    at mail.mail1.doGet(mail1.java:144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 501 Syntax error in arguments

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1625)
    ... 30 more
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 501 Syntax error in arguments

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1625)
    ... 30 more
```

Does it says my mail from wich I'm trying to send the email is bad formatted? i tyied several mail formats but nothing worked

Comment: Have you tried the solution depicted here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946227/error-501-by-sending-mail-using-swift-mailer

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the "@":

```
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username + "@yahoo.com"));
```

While you're fixing that, you might want to fix some of these other [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

And upgrade to a [newer version of JavaMail](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).

Comment: I tryed also adding @ and trying to fix all other common errors ... but nothing good happened :( :(

Comment: Please update your question with the new code and the new debug output showing the result.  By "nothing good happened" do you mean you got exactly the same failure as before?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed all changing the implementation. I followed this tutorial:
[Java Mail Sender](http://lancill.blogspot.it/2012/05/invio-email-con-java-mail.html)

It is in italian but it's easy to understand.